# Why my SQL Query not working on JDBC Java

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Here

```
cat="SHOP-Large";
String sql="select * 
    from payments as pay 
    inner join bookingstatus as bs ON pay.space_id=bs.space_id and bs.bookingstatus='Booked' and `bs.cat`="+cat+"";
```

This one is showing this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bs.cat' in 'on clause'
```

I have tried removing those backtics also

```
String sql="select * 
    from payments as pay 
    inner join bookingstatus as bs ON pay.space_id=bs.space_id 
    and bs.bookingstatus='Booked' and bs.cat="+cat+"";
```

This one shows:

```
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'SHOP' in 'on clause'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check if you made a typo in your database, sometimes a space or other characters are inserted

Comment: Do not concatenate values into a query string like that. It leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection (in this case you just get the 'benign' effect that is an error). Instead learn about prepared statements and parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your first and statement into a where statement. You will also need quotation marks for the variable cat.

For the second statement, try this:

```
String sql="select * 
from payments as pay 
inner join bookingstatus as bs ON pay.space_id=bs.space_id 
where bs.bookingstatus='Booked' and bs.cat='"+cat+"'";
```

This may not fix all your errors, but it will fix some.

Comment: Although this solves the immediate problem, it is not the correct solution. The correct solution would be to use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: Thanks it works i was missing quotation marks around variable cat.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Incorrect. That is only applicable if this program is part of a production environment. Judging from this question, I assume this is not going into a production environment. Even if it was, that would be helpful information, but it does not answer the question of why the asker's code is not working.

Comment: @Captain it is always applicable. If people don't learn the right way from the start, they are going to trip and do this in a production system as well.